# How to Process NDR emails from Exchange Server in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Currently my application has ability to process incoming emails and bounce then back if it does not match with given criteria in code. However, I want to add up another type of email to Process which are NDR "Non-Delivery Reports" from Microsoft Exchange Server. So my application do not responsd/Bounce back NDR to exchange server which cause a loop between my Mailbox and Exchange Server. 
Following method triggers when Invalid doesn't have a specific

```
private static void ProcessInvidMsgWithoutNo(string sMsgFrom, string sFromEmail, EmailMsg sMsgReceived, EmailMessage message)
    {
        EmailMsg.MoveToInvalid(message);

        sMsgReceived.IsValid = false;
        SaveMsgReceived(sMsgReceived, 0, string.Empty);

        if (!sFromEmail.Equals(string.Empty))
        {
            ResponseForInvidMsg(sFromEmail);
        }
        else
        {
            curLog.WriteLog(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, MsgEMChecker27, sMsgFrom));
        }
    }
```

Following Method triggers to respond incoming Invalid message as stated above.

```
private static void ResponseForInvidMsg(string sFromEmail)
    {
        string tErrSubjectMsg = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}\\Resource\\MsgErrorSubjectAck.html", Entity.GetSetting("DocRootDir"));

        StringBuilder htmlText = new StringBuilder();
        FileStream fsFile = new FileStream(tErrSubjectMsg, FileMode.Open);

        if (fsFile != null)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fsFile, Encoding.Default);

            string text;
            do
            {
                text = reader.ReadLine();
                if ((text != null) && (text != ""))
                    htmlText.Append(text + "\n");
            } while (text != null);

            reader.Close();
            fsFile.Close();
            fsFile = null;
        }
        else
            htmlText.Append("hello");

        string tToCustomerSubject = ReplyForInvalid;
        string tMessage = htmlText.ToString();

        EmailMsg emTo = new EmailMsg(string.Empty, sFromEmail, tToCustomerSubject, tMessage);
        emTo.MsgType = EmailMsg.TypeSentCustomer;
        emTo.Send(false); //Not save but CC to generic email box
    }
```

Please, help me to find a way where I can stop my code to respond Exchange Server NDR. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The place to start would be to check the ItemClass of the message see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-asemail/51d84da6-a2da-41e9-8ca7-eb6c4e72c28d . NDR's, delivery report etc should have a prefix of Report eg

```
REPORT.IPM.NOTE.NDR Non-delivery report for a standard message.
REPORT.IPM.NOTE.DR Delivery receipt for a standard message.
```